# Centering divs which contains other divs

Tags: html, css, alignment, inline, centering

I have a problem with centering divs. I am using text-align center, block, inline-block and it works until the divs are empty. After I put something it in the vertical align will be changed. See te attached photos. I will really appriciate if somebody can help me out of this. Thanks

```
 .white-title { 
font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Bold';
font-size: 20px;
color: #ff4f00;
}    

#section01 {
text-align: center;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#block01 {
background-image: url('images/01_block.png');
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 29px;
margin-right: 29px;
height: 274px;
width: 480px;
}

#block02 {
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 29px;
margin-right: 29px;
height: 274px;
width: 480px;
}    

<div id="section01">
    <div id="block01">
        <div class="white-title" style="text-align: center;">ERRE KERESTÜNK 2014</div>
    </div>
    <div id="block02">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/NUupD4a0Yx4?rel=0&amp%3Bcontrols=0..." width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Empty div: [empty div image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ffc4k42mo1icb6v/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-03%20at%2012.39.36.png?dl=0)
Fully div: [fully div image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/43xc0p27gvx8a4u/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-03%20at%2012.41.09.png?dl=0)

Comment: try margin: 0 auto; for your inner div

Comment: @Zoltan, i think what Rahul Sutar has explained will work for you..!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the `vertical-align` property to your `block02` Id in the style. like below:-

```
     #block02 
       {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 29px;
        margin-right: 29px;
        height: 274px;
        width: 480px;
        vertical-align: top;    /* this needs to be added */
    }
```

Comment: Please don't paste invalid code. You should also remove the `style` tags. It would be best if you only add the new property.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this trick:

```
#section01 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```